Dynamic select from list for discord bot
I send a modal to the user and expect a response from the user, after receiving it, it is processed and receives a list (there are no more than 20 elements in the list), and also sends a select to the user with a choice from this list. I got this error:
for character in character_in_raid ['name']]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'character_in_raid' is not defined

This is my current code:
class logs_input(discord.ui.Modal, title="Test"):
    tst = discord.ui.TextInput(label="1")    
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        log_code = self.tst.value
        response = get_token()
        store_token(response)
        log_parse = get_logs.log_character(log_code)
        global character_in_raid
        character_in_raid = log_parse['rankedCharacters']
        for character in character_in_raid:
            print(character)
        await interaction.response.send_message(view=Select_buyer())


class Select_buyer(discord.ui.View):
        
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder = "Choose buyer",
        min_values=0, max_values=20, 
        options= [discord.SelectOption
            (label=character['name'], value=character['name'])
                 for character in character_in_raid ['name']]
    )

    async def buyer_select(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        selected_values = select.values
        print(selected_values)
        await interaction.response.send_message(selected_values)

I tried making the variable global, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me with this? I'll appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!

Try this:
class _Select(discord.ui.Select):
        def __init__(self, list_options:List[discord.SelectOption]):
            super().__init__(options=list_options)

        async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
              selected_values = self.values
              await interaction.response.send_message(selected_values)

class Select_buyer(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, list_options:List[discord.SelectOption]):
        super().__init__()
        self.component=_Select(list_options)
        self.add_item(self.component)

And then, at the end of your logs_input class
options = [discord.SelectOption(label=character['name'], value=character['name']) for character in character_in_raid]
await interaction.response.send_message(view=Select_buyer(list_options=options))


Added, the error remains the same

Be sure to replace your Select_buyer class with mine

Oh, it works. Thanks a lot
